# Facing CORS policy No "Access-control-allow-origin" Error while fetching data from third party API in SPFx

Tags: heroku, heroku-api

I am facing CORS policy No "Access-control-allow-origin" Error while fetching data from third party API in SPFx, and to resolve this I was using herokuapp(https://howling-crypt-nnnnn.herokuapp.com) to call third-party API but somehow this herokuapp is down as per attached screenshot

is there any way to resolve this herokuapp issue?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZI9qx.png)

I have tried to access using postman but unable to get access

Answer (score 0):

If you get a CROSS Origin error on an API then: You need to add CORS headers on the API at the server side,

- If you own the Server Side API, then you can get around this by
  adding the headers. Depending on the technology used, it may vary how
  you implement this.
- If you do not own the API, then you need to
  contact and request the API developer/provider to add these headers
  for your domain or a generic CORS header.
- In the worst case, you may
  have to write a proxy API to pipe the response from your api to your
  front end.

Comment: I have done that but how should I up my heroku proxy server ?

Comment: Which tech stack are you using on the backend heroku app?